# Chaos theory textbook

Tags: reference-request, chaos-theory

I'm looking for a textbook discussing logistic map and chaos theory that is:

1. Mathematically rigorous. In definition-theorem format (because I like it when the steps are clear, concrete and compact). But preferably more focused on the algebraic results, than on defining objects merely for an alternate mathematical perspective.
2. Contains algebraic results in line with recent research. I'm aware much of chaos cannot be explained algebraically yet.
3. Can contain numerical explanations too, but not overstepping the algebraic ones.

I read some chapters from Strogatz. It's nice but doesn't say much about algebraic results of logistic map beyond the 2-period cycle and it's not 100% clear because he omits some steps and definitions.

Edit: Suggestions are appreciated even if they don't satisfy all the points. But no pop-sci please.

Comment: Did you know about this? http://chaosbook.org/

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti looks decent and fits the requirements. Thanks.

Comment: @caverac No. Seems more like video lecture than text?

Comment: @LewisParker If you click on the side bar `By chapter` you will find the PDFs there

Comment: Got it. Will check it. Thanks for the reco.

Comment: Might be of interest: [Self-study book for dynamical systems theory? (physics)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353841/75633).

Comment: I'd also mention [Guckenheimer Holmes](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1140-2).